# Visual Studios create Standalone Javascript React Project. npm ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! syscall open

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, visual-studio, npm

When trying to create a new [Standalone Javascript React Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixIYg.png) in Visual Studios 2020, as I have many times before on other computers, I am getting this [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aO7tq.png) that it can't find package.json.

I have tried npm init, npm uninstall then reinstall,
also uninstalling and reinstalling create-react-app.

I have tried this in my main folder and at
path C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE

To try and create package.json all with no success.

This should just default create, any ideas?

Edit:
It creates this empty project [Empty Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/205eR.png)
Also if I separately use npx create-react-app it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get it to work I found where one of the package.json files was and copy and pasted it to

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE

For now, it seems to be working if anyone comes behind me and gets as fed up as I have.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I didn't quite understand your problem but try this.

1. First,

   ```
   npm init -y
   ```

   in the terminal. This will create a package.json file.
2. Second, create an index.js file in the same directory where you type
   in your code.
3. Third, Go to package.json file and add a script `"start":"node index.js"`then, go to the terminal and type  `npm start`. or, you
   can just do `node index.js` in the terminal without adding script in package.json.

Comment: I edited the prompt to hopefully provide make it more clear that I'm using the out-of-the-box Visual Studios project creation. So I don't have an index.js file or package.json file before creating anything.